# Waiting for call to finish and then dispatch action in saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I want to make call to server and then use that data for dispatch of other action.

```
export function* function1(actions) {
      console.log('inside');
      try {
        console.log('getting past orders list');
        const url = `/api/getOrders`;
        let reqsData = {
          order_id: actions.payload.order_id
        };
        const data = yield call(request, { url, method: 'POST', data:reqsData })
        console.log(data);
        console.log('///////////////////////////////////');
        if (!data.error) {
          console.log(data)
          yield put({ type: 'nowThis', payload: actions.payload.data });
        } else {
          console.log('---------------------------------')
          console.log('got some error');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
```

But It is not running code next to line 
        **const data = yield call(request, { url, method: 'POST', data:reqsData })**

I have similar code before which is running properly + i checked the network and i am getting response 200 for this line.

I have used **fork** in place of **call** but it run my code next to that line before the call is complete.

Comment: Is it breaking on that line ? does it goes to catch block ? if yes, then can you share the error.

Comment: @Fawaz Not it is not throwing any error and in network section of browser I have checked the response of request `200`

Comment: Check in the console section of browser, the console log of your catch block.

Comment: @Fawaz it is not printing anything in .catch but in .then i am getting response

Comment: Could you add an example of how you use the saga outside ?

Comment: `.then` -> its not in your sample. If you are using .then in your `request`, just remove it.

Comment: @Fawaz no nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

yield call takes function and arguments. Write a method to make a service call. U can use axios npm package (axios.get('../url',params:{params})) and call that function in yield call.

yield call(methodToCallApi(),params,to,method). also, it is better if you keep services calls in a seperate file and just call those methods in saga, instead of defining directly in saga.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `request` method is not returning properly. Wrap that in a `Promise`:

```
request() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    myApiCall().then(response => {
      resolve(response);
    }).catch(e => {
      reject(e);
    });
  });
}
```

and then in your saga, you can `yield` as normal:

```
const data = yield call(request, { url, method: 'POST', data:reqsData })
```